# How do I add different images for different app 'flavors'?

Tags: react-native, webpack, react-native-image

I've built a React Native app which has 2 versions - production and dev.  I've created slightly different app icons and added these in XCode & Android Studio, and those are working fine.  However, I have a screen within the app which needs a logo, and I'm having trouble getting the appropriate logo to show on that screen.

I've uploaded both versions of the logo to the assets folder, but with different names, and then added the appropriate name to each .env file:

```
LOGO=logo_main.png  // In .env.prod
LOGO=logo_dev.png   // In .env.dev
```

Then, on the screen in question, I have a simple Image with the source pulled from the .env file, like this:

```
<Image source={require(`../../../assets/${Config.LOGO}`)} />
```

(`Config` uses `react-native-config-reader` to read the config file).

However, this doesn't work (on iOS at least) due to webpack not having access to the config file when it's getting the images together.

I can't find anything online which explains how to do this, but I assume it's possible as it seems like a basic thing to do.  Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different `bundleId`'s for different flavours and then based on `bundleId` choose an appropriate image.

Comment: Thanks... can you give me a rough idea how to do that?  Do you mean that I would have something like an if statement, like if(bundleId = devVersion) { useDevImage }else {useProdImage}?

Comment: Yes, pretty much like that.

Comment: but in this case both images should be consider in compile time ?  if i created dev build then only devImage should be take from compiler  and ProdImages should be ignore .so app size should not be increase.  any idea how to archive this ?